# Send-Mailmessage from command with variable body

Tags: email, powershell, command

Below script should check if files have been created today and send an email to one of our users.

The problem is that I can't send more than one value in the body. I need to remove "File" from body to get the email out. Also there is one email for each file. I would rewrite it to send one mail with all files listed with dates.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Files changed today %date%

FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO (
  set tf=%%~tA
  set fd=!tf:~0,10!
  if !fd!==%date% ( 
    powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage ^
      -SmtpServer this.server.com ^
      -To my@email.com ^
      -From noreply@possibly.fake ^
      -Subject Updated^
      -Body "%%A File"
  )
)
```

So i actually got this working with some heavy googeling (even went to page 3 at one point)

This is my "Check files in folder and send email with whats new and whats old"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Files changed today %date%
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO (
  set tf=%%~tA
  set fd=!tf:~0,10!
  if !fd!==%date% ( 
      set "file=!file! <br> %%A !tf!"
    )
  if NOT !fd!==%date% ( 
      set "old=!old! <br> %%A !tf!"
    )
)
set "file=!file!
set "old=!old!

set "today=<b>New today:</b> %file%"
set "older=<b>Older files</b> %old%"
set "body=!today! <br><br> !older!"

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml^
        -SmtpServer yourserver.com^
        -To your@mail.com ^
        -From noreply@possibly.fake ^
        -Subject Updated^
        -Body '!body!'
```

Comment: Drop batch and write the whole thing in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

[Im]pure PowerShell solution without a batch file, save it to a file with `.ps1` extension:

```
$modifiedToday = gci | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date }
Send-MailMessage `
    -SmtpServer this.server.com `
    -To my@email.com `
    -From noreply@possibly.fake `
    -Subject Updated `
    -Body ($modifiedToday -join "`n")
```

Impure because it uses abbreviated aliases like `gci` and `?{` instead of Get-ChildItem and Where-Object as I really don't like the verboseness of officially recommended PowerShell code style. As someone who doesn't mind writing cryptic batch-file code the OP might appreciate that as well.